# github for windows not showing my changes made in eclipse

Tags: windows, eclipse, github

I've installed github for windows.
I cloned a repository to my local drive.
But when i make some changes into my app from eclipse, the changes doesn't come in github for windows .
hoping a reply soon .

P.S. I am a noob

Comment: Did you commit it after you were done?

Comment: It is showing no uncommited changes

Comment: Are you actually "working" on the Working copy? Once you cloned your Repo you need to make sure you are actually working in the working copy. You don't mention how you have everything setup so it would be a guess from here, but it sounds like you have more than one copy.

Comment: no . I am working on the correct directory that was created by the github

Comment: Oh! sorry .. I was in the wrong directory .. Github created two copies of the project ..  Thanx for reminding me about this . :)

Comment: Nice, there are plenty of Git tutorials that explain how it works and what to expect when fetching/commiting. This is a good place to start. http://learn.github.com/p/intro.html

Answer (score 1):

**For anyone else reading this**: if you generate a large amount of untracked/modified data, the GitHub Windows app sometimes appears to be ignorant of **all** recent changes.

**For example**: if you generate a bunch of untracked Doxygen files (~500MB), it may take GitHub a *very* long time to finally show "Uncommitted changes". In the meantime, you may not see **any** of your changes.

If your git bash shows changes, and your GitHub gui does not, then this is likely your issue.